# Linguagem C - Problema de somatório dentro de uma função

Tags: c

Boa tarde.

O programa tem a seguinte finalidade. Tenho que mandar o usuário digitar quantos alunos a sala tem, para que assim, ele mande esse número para uma função(no caso, cada matéria é uma função), e dentro destas funções tenho uma outra função genérica que uso para o usuário digitar as notas e fazer a média.

```
/*Fazer um programa para calcular as médias de cada disciplina utilizando função,
onde cada disciplina é uma função diferente e na função principal mostre todas as médias;*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

float matematica(int);
float portugues(int);
float biologia(int);
float geografia(int);
float fisica(int);
float digitarNotasFor(int);
int i;

int main(void) {

    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    int qtd;

    printf("Digite a quantidade de alunos em sala = ");
    scanf("%d",&qtd);

    matematica(qtd);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

float matematica(int n) {
    printf("\nMatemática\n");
    float media = digitarNotasFor(n);
    return printf("\nA média em matemática é = %.2f\n",media);
}

float digitarNotasFor(int n) {

    float notas[n],contaMedia = 0;
    printf("\nDigite as notas\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Aluno[%d] = ",i);
        scanf("%d",&notas[i]);
        contaMedia = contaMedia + notas[i];
    }

    return (contaMedia/n);
}
```

Resumindo o problema, ele entra nas duas funções, mas quando me retorna a média, sempre aparece o 0. Pelo que eu observei, o valor do somatório da variável `contaMedia` continua com o mesmo valor constante que eu coloquei para não trazer 'lixo' do meu sistema. Isso é, está 0 no caso, me retorna 0 a média, se eu colocar 1, me retorna 1.

OBS: Eu resumi o código, retirando as outras funções/matérias para ficar melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Descobri qual foi meu erro, quando se usa o tipo float, dentro do scanf fica "%f" e não %d, que seria para o tipo int.

Na ocasião, estava

```
scanf("%d",&notas[i]);
```

E na realidade, deveria ficar desse jeito

```
scanf("%f",&notas[i]);
```